# Is it possible to replace Windows on an eMMC without any external device?

Tags: grub2, wubi

I've managed to do the following so far:

Installed Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS from WUBIUEFI (a fork of WUBI for modern versions of Windows)

Managed to create a separate partition with just an ISO and used grml rescueboot to make an easy entry on GRUB trough mounting to /boot/grml (i had to manually allow GRUB on the BIOS beforehand or it would only boot to windows)

Booting to the live CD is doable and works.

What should I do to install and ensure the best results?

All of my USB Ports are dead and have no SD Card slot. if I managed to get the liveCD to work, then what's the last part to ensure it would work?

Comment: Honestly, I would just spend the $5 and get a 4GB flash drive from your nearest Walmart/CVS/Staples.

Comment: Unfortunatley, my USB ports are dead. so i have to improvise here. Would it work though?

Comment: I really have no idea; I've never tried something like that before. That's probably something that [Rod Smith](https://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith) could answer though. He is an expert in UEFI and dual-booting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you format the ext4 partition before you install - in case you make a mistake and the partition with the Live CD is damaged.

Then just continue to install. Of course, it's not ideal conditions, but it should work.

---

You might find it easier to simply make a 4GB partition and format it as fat - then use UNetBootin or similar and treat it as a standard USB stick.

Comment: Yeah, the ISO file is already in a dedicated, EXT4 Partition for this very reason. i just mounted to boot/gmrl for the purpose of getting an easier grub entry (as my previous attempts failed at adding a custom menu entry)

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. Are you planning on installing to that ext4 partition?

Comment: i was sort-of planning to install from that EXT4 Partition (as an partition for the  ISO only) to the Old And formatted (after ensuring it works) NTFS and the Images Partition. i already made a copy of the OEM Key if it doesn't work and have to resort using PXE to restore the eMMC to it's previous state.

Comment: @Darkmega.EXE that sounds good then. As long as all your files are backed up, you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully that helps getting me started with a fresh install of xubuntu.